# Voltage limitation circuit for analog signal

Tags: voltage, analog

I want to design a circuit which takes two analog signals with a DC-offset via koax inputs, and forwards them.

In between the voltages should be capped at a user-defined level (between 200 mV and 500 mV), if the input voltage is higher, then it should be capped at the cutoff level. The reaction time of the circuit should be as fast as possible. The input signals have a frequency up to ~2-3 kHz. What is the best way to achieve that?

Bonus: Amplification of the signals in the circuit is also possible.

Comment: "as fast as possible" is not a reasonable measure, especially when your signals are this slow (3 kHz is nearly DC, for someone working with high frequency signals).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Instantaneous would be the best, but that is impossible (The circuit should serve as a voltage protection, and I do not know how long the circuit behind this one can operate at overvoltage. Thus: The faster, the better). And I have no idea of general time scales for such operations...

Comment: It's generally hard to say, but even for the most old-school semiconductors, assume bandwidths of Megahertzes.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that you have to deal with very low-frequency signals (<3 kHz), the easiest approach here would be something like abusing the voltage clipping properties of a real Opamp:

By doing something like

```
--> Amp1 (gain = 10) --> Zener-based voltage limiter --> attenuator (gain = 1/10) -->
```

you could have something that works like that without disturbing the signal all too much.

To explain:

to limit voltages, and, for example, generate a stable reference voltage or cut away voltage spikes in power supplies, you'd simply do

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frz4fX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Zener diode used is a peculiar semiconductor: It works pretty well as a diode, i.e. it inhibits flowing of current from the positive side to the negative side, up to a breakdown voltage, from which on it becomes very conductive (i.e. low resistance).

Now, since this is not adjustable, you can't use it in your "user-defined level" scenario.

Hence, you'll need adjustable gain on the input, and the inverse gain at the output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVZ28s.png)</sup>

Note that you get adjustable overall gain as "bonus".

This is the rare case where it makes sense to chose a high gain for the  opamp stage – the higher the gain here, the higher breakdown Zener voltage you can select, and the more "exact" and less distorted your output becomes. However, if you select a Zener diode (or diode cascade) with a high voltage, you will also need to make sure your Opamp has a supply voltage that can generate that at all.

By the way, you might want to read up on Opamp circuits and active and passive filters – it would make potentially a lot of sense to integrate a low-pass filter in the output stage (which really isn't more than adding a capacitor), since the clipping operation probably has much higher bandwidth than your 3 kHz signal, and I don't know what that does to your signal chain; but that's something that I can't consider without knowing what you want to do with the signal in the end.

Comment: Note to more advanced experimenters might be adding an output resistance to OA1, to get more benefit of the V-I curve of the zener or diodes, depending on selection, making a "smoother clip".

Comment: @Asmyldof a "smooth clip" is *exactly* what you'd want to avoid! When you want voltage limiting, you're typically going for the sharpest possible clip; a smooth clip implies a non-linear distortion near the breakdown voltage, and that means very funky behaviour for signals that "do not quite clip", spectrum-wise.

Comment: It depends on the signal whether you want it or not. In audio maybe not, but I see no "This is for Audio". BTW, just noticed, your second amp still amplifies.

Comment: @Asmyldof shoot, you're right G2 > 1 !

Comment: (PS: I have used R-Diode in Audio, which gives a somewhat unusual sound when clipping, but none of those harmful microsecond flanks that hurt your ears and speakers, and... you're already clipping anyway. It's a matter of getting the right R and right diodes.) -- Edit: I _am_ talking about half to 5 times the dynamic R of the diode here, not 100's of k's

Comment: @Asmyldof I was assuming OP is doing some analog signal measurements, and needs her/his dynamic range, but yes, in many cases, close to clipping on the input stage, fidelity doesn't matter anymore, anyway.

Comment: @Asmyldof also, note that I might be a little overcautious – I'm from a radio background, and hence, I tend to see the mixer in every non-perfect amplifier, and all the intermodulation products that produces in (read in Gollum's voice) my precious signal.

Comment: @Asmyldof yet another note: with a diode (typically, in fwd direction) in the feedback of an opamp, you'd build a logarithmic amplifier – which kind of is the same circuit, but with a highly "smoothed clipping" and a total (intended) loss of linearity.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't mean "highly". Just that op-amps swinging up (or down, of course) tend to happily force a very small corner radius at clipping, with a few hundred ohm, you can double or triple that corner radius.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, clipping introduces high-frequency artifacts, but when I notice them, I can reduce the gain and run the transmission again. Main task for the circuit is voltage protection, and else linear transmission of the input.

Comment: How would your circuit limit the negative possible voltage? Afaik at the moment it only cuts the positive peaks.

Comment: @arc_lupus that is right! However, nothing else than positive voltages have ever been asked for. Anyway, just use a series of two Zeners, each having a different direction, and you're fine.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Not explicitly stated, that is correct. So if I set the second zener between the first one and GND, and make it antiparallel, that should be fine?

Comment: yes, you explicitly stated you wanted to cut off voltages **over** a certain threshold. Anyway, yes if you do `internal---|<|-----|>|---GND`, you should be fine, as said.